# Proper Hibernate id generator for postgres serial/bigserial column?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, mapping, hibernate-mapping

My PostgreSQL tables have id's of type `bigserial`, meaning they are generated at the time rows are inserted (and thus, the id column's value is not supplied in the `INSERT` statement).  I'm having difficulty finding the proper value for the `<generator class="...">` attribute in my XML mapping file.

The code below is the closest I've found that seems to be the closest for Postgres, but it's still performing a `SELECT nextval(...)` on the sequence before inserting (and explicitly including the id field's value on the insert).  I just want Hibernate to not include the id field value at all, allowing Postgres to do its job of generating the value itself.

```
    <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">my_sequence_name</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is undocumented but you can actually use an `identity` generator with PostgreSQL when the PK is of type `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL`:

```
<id name="id" column="user_id" type="java.lang.Long">
     <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

See <strike>[HB-875](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-875)</strike> and [HHH-1675](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1675) for background on this.

Comment: For new versions (JPA): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979746/mapping-postgresql-serial-type-with-hibernate-annotations

Answer (score 4):

From what i read:

```
<id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">my_sequence_name</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

should work faster than:

```
<id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

The sequence generator falls in the **Non-insert POID generators** described like this:

> Non-insert POID generators are the best option for new applications.
>   These generators allow NHibernate to assign an identity to a
>   persistent object without writing the object's data to thedatabase,
>   allowing NHibernate to delay writing until the business transaction is
>   complete, reducing round trips to the database.

While the identity generator is **Post-insert POID generators** group:

> Post-insert POID generators require data to be persisted to the
>   database for an ID to be generated. *This alters the behavior of
>   NHibernate in very subtle ways and disables some performance features.
>   As such, use of these POID generators is strongly discouraged!* They
>   should only be used with existing databases where other applications
>   rely on this behavior.

Quotes were taken from NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook.

Comment: It looks like your two blocks of code that you're comparing are identical, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Tried following and it worked:

```
<id name="id" column="id" type="long" unsaved-value="null" >
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">my_sequence_name</param>
        </generator>
</id>
```