# Hibernate columns mismatch on persistance

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, ejb-3.0, hibernate-entitymanager

I've been trying to create EJB-based registration user transaction manager for registration purposes - it is very basic prototype, so please don't be concerned with unhashed passwords etc.

The issue I'm currently struggling with is column mismatch on persist method called from dao. The core of the problem is fact, that hibernate tries to insert into ID the value passed as the username.

I did [find](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=932155) some similar issues solved, but they were due hibernate's auto-generated tables' naming conflicts, which should not be the case here, as the 'Id' table is explicitly marked as primary key.

I'm geniuelly out of ideas why would hibernate act this way, especially since I've been using it with SpringBeans in single war earlier and now the same hibernate code is not working with standalone EJB.

```
16:18:59,935 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) user in dao: User with id='0', name='username1', password='password1', with 0 roles
16:18:59,965 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) Hibernate: insert into public.users (password, username) values (?, ?)
    16:18:59,970 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 9) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003
    16:18:59,971 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 9) Bad value for type int : username1
```

register function in my Dao

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class UsersDaoImpl implements UsersDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void register(User user, Set<Role> roles) {
        em.persist(user); //Line of code that results with the exception
        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        em.flush();
    }

    /*other methods ommitted*/
}
```

User entity class - Id value is set as auto-generated inside the database's table definition.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User implements Serializable{
public User(){
}

public User(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id",unique = true,nullable = false, insertable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name ="username", unique = true,nullable = false)
private String username;

@Column(name ="password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(name = "flag", insertable = false)
private boolean active;
/*I have ommitted other values as they were not the part of this table*/
}
```

And here's the JBOSS log from the remote register call:

```
16:18:59,935 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) user in dao: User with id='0', name='username1', password='password1', with 0 roles
16:18:59,965 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) Hibernate: insert into public.users (password, username) values (?, ?)
16:18:59,970 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 9) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003
16:18:59,971 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 9) Bad value for type int : username1
16:18:59,974 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor] (EJB default - 9) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Bad value for type int : username1
16:18:59,977 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 9) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component UsersDaoImpl for method public abstract void UsersDao.register(mappings.User,java.util.Set): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Bad value for type int : username1
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:139) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:204) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:306) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at dao.UsersDao$$$view12.register(Unknown Source) [ejb.jar:]
        at service.UserManagerBean.registerUser(UserManagerBean.java:45) [ejb.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:302) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$200(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:196) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Bad value for type int : username1
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:859) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:563) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at dao.UsersDaoImpl.register(UsersDaoImpl.java:65) [ejb.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:202) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 66 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Bad value for type int : username1
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:134) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.get(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:120) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:100) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:725) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:701) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:705) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:853) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        ... 87 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type int : username1
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2934)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2137)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getInt(WrappedResultSet.java:1052)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        ... 108 more



}
```

Comment: It could be the way you have declared the Id column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979746/mapping-postgresql-serial-type-with-hibernate-annotations

Comment: I have tried the solution presented in the linked article, but it seems hibernate then tries to use it's own sequence for serial, starting with id=0 - this solution is not working with populated database such as mine.
When i'm using the '@GenerationType=Identity' it does create the entity inside the database with it's default values (creation time == now, id from the database's sequence), but the error above still pops up trying (unsuccesfully) rollback the transaction, without even trying to set the cascaded values. It's like hibernate is not realizing it did proper insert, thus aborting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to find the solution to the problem.

Apparently hibernate (4.0.1Final) has problems with order of the @Id annotated column when used without spring.

```
    username    |    password    | last_login |       creation_date        | id | flag
----------------+----------------+------------+----------------------------+----+------
```

@ID column has to be the first column in the table for hibernate to map it properly.

```
 id | username  | password  | last_login |       creation_date        | flag
----+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+------
```