# How to define database generated column values as readonly fields in JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mariadb, readonly

With MariaDB 10.2 it's possible to define default value for Datetime e.g. created and lastModified.

How I should access this columns as readonly field? Because this values should only be under control of the database and should not be modified from code, but I want read access to this property in code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's simple. Just set the `insertable` and `updatable` attributes to `false`.

```
@Column(
    name = "created_on", 
    insertable = false, 
    updatable = false
)
private Timestamp createdOn;
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. But also I had a `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'someobject0_.somereadonlyfield' in 'field list'` when I tried to delete `someobject` by default `JpaRepository` method: `someObjectsRepository.deleteById(someObjectId)`. Custom delete query helped me: `@Query("delete from someobject where id = :someObjectId", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not exclude the column from delete queries, so it is not read-only.

Comment: @DanielRusev Delete is for rows, not columns. Column values are gone when the row is deleted, no matter whether they were read-only or writable.

Comment: You do have rows if you the field is collection valued of basic, non-entity type like a list of long's;

Comment: That's totally unrelated to the answer or my previous comment

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
@Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
private YourType field;
```

Where the `@Column` is used to specify the mapped column for a persistent property or field. In particular it is `javax.persistence.Column`.