# Is it possible to have autoincrement number without it being an ID?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I keep googling and find that the only way is to use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Identity)
```

But I already have a primary key, I just need another field that auto increments. It's really hard to code it by manual calculation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping PostgreSQL serial type with Hibernate annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979746/mapping-postgresql-serial-type-with-hibernate-annotations)

Comment: No, just tried @Column(name = "internalID")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private Long internalID; and it didn't do anything. Value is null after insert

Comment: What if you do `@Column(name = "internalID")` and then `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`?

Comment: Nope, nulls after inserts

Comment: @erotsppa Could you explain why do you what it? What is the initial problem that you try to solve.

Comment: @SternK I have an entity that already has an id field. The id is a primary key and I cant change it in production. The id is not sequential for this table GenerationType = AUTO. Now I have a need to add a new column that shows a sequential number for a user for any new rows

Answer (score 4):

I see the following options:

1) You can use [@Generated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-Generated) annotation.

You should have a table declared in the following way:

```sql
create sequence TST_DATA_SEQ increment by 1 start with 1;

create table TST_DATA (
   ...
   dat_auto integer default nextval('TST_DATA_SEQ'),
   ...
);
```

and appropriate column in the entity:

```java
   @Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   @Column(name = "dat_auto", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Long auto;
```

Note that according to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated):

> Properties marked as generated must additionally be non-insertable and non-updateable.

So, hibernate will make additional query to populate the `auto` field after flushing.

```java
   Data data = new Data();
   // filling fields except data.auto
   session.persist(data);
   session.flush();
```

```
insert into TST_DATA (dat_name, dat_id) 
values (?, ?)

Hibernate: /* get generated state com.example.hibernate.Data */
  select data_.dat_auto as dat_auto_0_ 
  from TST_DATA data_ 
  where data_.dat_id=?
```

2) You can use [@GeneratorType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-GeneratorType) annotation.

You should have an implementation of hibernate `ValueGenerator`. The simple example you can see below.

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.tuple.ValueGenerator;

public class MyGenerator implements ValueGenerator<Long> 
{
   public Long generateValue(Session session, Object owner)
   {
      return (
         (BigInteger) session
            .createNativeQuery("select nextval('TST_DATA_SEQ')")
            .getSingleResult()
         ).longValue();
   }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```java
   @GeneratorType(type = MyGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
   @Column(name = "dat_auto")
   private Long auto;
```

In this case you should not provide the default value for the column declaration as was required in n1. and the appropriate entity field should not have `@Column(... insertable = false, updatable = false)`. Each time when this entity will be persisted, hibernate generates query:

```
select nextval('TST_DATA_SEQ')
```

and populate this value to the `auto` field.

Comment: Both of these solutions require create sequence TST_DATA_SEQ, do you know how to automate this as part of spring startup? I dont want to resort to my CD pipeline to do this kind of thing

Comment: Actually I tried your second solution, and it went into an infinite loop inside generateValue()

Comment: As for sequence creation, look at spring boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html). I tested both proposed approachs on the simple application (with only hibernate 5.4.4.Final dependency) and they work fine. It looks like your problem with `an infinite loop inside generateValue()` is related to integration with your project.

Comment: @erotsppa, a bit too late, but adding `.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT)` prevents the infinite loop (at least in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try:

```
@GeneratedValue(GenerationType.strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="internal_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="internal_seq", sequenceName="internal_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name="internalID")
public Long internalID;
```

Comment: Nope, nulls on create