# Hibernate (Generate non prime value only when it is null)

Tags: java, hibernate, generated

I am trying to find a way how to generate value using "org.hibernate.annotations.Generated"
at the moment on every insert it will increase .But i would like to know if its passable to do it only when the value is null.

```
@Column(name = "number", columnDefinition = "sequence")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Long number;
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216566/6277104) will be helpful.

Comment: does not help :S