# Custom sequence column creation (non-Id) - Jpa Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, entity

I need to have an event_number column in my events table, which can uniquely identify each row, but this column is not the @Id of the table. Each event_number must follow some format like `EVENT100001,EVENT100002,...`

I went through `@GeneratedValue` annotation and found that this only can be used with @Id columns. But then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/536102/4911177) answer but not sure whether it causes any race conditions.

Is there any cleaner way of doing this? Here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "event_number", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String eventNumber;
}
```

Comment: Should  the `eventNumber` value be generated based on the `id`, or it's completely independent.

Comment: It's completely independent, only requirement is that it should follow the sequence `EVENT100001,EVENT100002,...` and `EVENT100001` should be the starting value.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216566/6277104) will be helpful

Comment: This doesn't support the alphanumeric requirement in my case

Comment: You just should use `MyGenerator implements ValueGenerator<String>`. and then slightly modify `generateValue` by adding a prefix that you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@GeneratorType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-GeneratorType) annotation.

You should have an implementation of hibernate `ValueGenerator`. The simple example you can see below.

```java
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.tuple.ValueGenerator;

public class EventGenerator implements ValueGenerator<String> 
{
   public String generateValue(Session session, Object owner)
   {
      return  "EVENT" + session
            .createNativeQuery("select nextval('TST_DATA_SEQ')")
            .getSingleResult();
   }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```java
@GeneratorType(type = EventGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "event_number")
private String eventNumber;
```

Comment: My application is based on mySql and doesn't support sequence, so had to change the strategy on getting unique value. To get the sequence values, I created a table with id column set to autoincrement starting `100001` and wrote a stored procedure which inserts a value into this table and returns the the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. In the `generateValue` method instead of the call to get next value, I am invoking the stored procedure.

Now, I'm facing a new error. Updating the question with more details